# Mitsuo Sugiura's caluculation of $I=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ in his "Introduction to Analysis 1".

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, change-of-variable

What is $I=\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$?

Mitsuo Sugiura's answer in his "Introduction to Analysis 1" is like the following:

> Let $x=\tan\theta$.
> Then, $I=\int\frac{\sec^2\theta}{\sec\theta}d\theta=\int\frac{d\theta}{\cos\theta}=\log\left|\frac{1+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\right|=\log\left|x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right|$.

Sugiura calculated $\sqrt{x^2+1}=\sec\theta$.
But what happens if $\sqrt{x^2+1}=-\sec\theta$?

---

Let $\varphi:(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})\ni\theta\mapsto\tan\theta\in\mathbb{R}.$
Let $t=\varphi(\theta)$.
Then,
$dt=\phi'(\theta)d\theta=\sec^2\theta d\theta$,
$\sqrt{t^2+1}=\sqrt{(\varphi(\theta))^2+1}=\sqrt{\tan^2\theta+1}=\sqrt{\sec^2\theta}=-\sec\theta$.

Let $c$ be a fixed point in $(\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})$.
Let $x\in (\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2})$.
$I=\int_{c}^{x}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^2+1}}+C=\int_{\varphi^{-1}(c)}^{\varphi^{-1}(x)}\frac{\sec^2\theta d\theta}{-\sec\theta}+C=\int_{\varphi^{-1}(c)}^{\varphi^{-1}(x)}(-\sec\theta) d\theta+C=-\log\left(-\frac{1+\sin(\varphi^{-1}(x))}{\cos(\varphi^{-1}(x))}\right)+C'=-\log\left(-\tan(\varphi^{-1}(x))-\frac{1}{\cos(\varphi^{-1}(x))}\right)+C'=-\log(-x+\sqrt{x^2+1})+C'=\log(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})+C'$.

Even if $\sqrt{x^2+1}=-\sec\theta$, Sugiura's answer is correct.
Is this a coincidence?

Comment: When you compute indefinite integrals you should not worry so much about the domain of the functions or the sign they take at a certain place, you should only worry about finding ONE antiderivative. This is because any other antiderivative will differ only by a constant from the one you found.

Comment: @azif00 Thank you very much for your answer. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$. So, we should only worry about finding ONE antiderivative.

Comment: You do not need to care about justification of each step. The effect comes at the end. If the derivative of the final function is equal to the original one then the result is correct.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thank you very much!